# Toggle class will not close my sidebar after clicking the second time

Tags: jquery, toggle

I use the following jQuery to toggle between an `class`. It will add `open` when toggle-sidebar is clicked and close the other ones on the page, but I can't close the current one if I click the second time when I want to close the sidebar.

My code:

```
$('.toggle-sidebar').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('section aside').removeClass('open');
            $(this).parent().find('aside').toggleClass('open');
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So:

```
$('section aside').removeClass('open');
```

removes `open` class from all `aside` even from current. So it doesn't have an `open` class now.

And this

```
$(this).parent().find('aside').toggleClass('open');
```

adds `open` class to current `aside`. So you in fact don't have codes for removing `open` class from current `aside`.

I think you should check: if current `aside` has open `class` - then only remove it, otherwise - add and remove from other `aside`s. Kinda:

```
$('.toggle-sidebar').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var aside$ = $(this).parent().find('aside');
    if ( aside$.hasClass('open') ) {
        aside$.removeClass('open');
    } else {
        $('section aside').removeClass('open');
        aside$.addClass('open');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This was what I am looking for.